# Microsoft Fakes Framework - I can't use internal class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-assembly, microsoft-fakes

I'v a problem with Fakes Framework and internal class.
I've just readed and used the advice here: [How to mock/isolate internal classes in VS 2012 with Fakes Framework shims?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573112/how-to-mock-isolate-internal-classes-in-vs-2012-with-fakes-framework-shims)

but, I still not see internal classes.

I've this solution:
ACQTool (class library project)
ACQTool.UnitTests (test project)

in ACQTool namespace there is ACQTool.Utils internal class.

in ACQTool/AssemblyInfo.cs I've added these lines:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("ACQTool.UnitTests, PublicKey=57ad8399-13fd-4d4d-90fd-c521c2164d25")]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("ACQTool.Fakes, PublicKey=0024..47bc")]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Microsoft.QualityTools.Testing.Fakes, PublicKey=0024..47bc")]
```

After build, I can use ACQTool.Utils in test class, but not exist ACQTool.Fakes.ShimUtils/StubUtils.
Help me please.

Comment: Do you have `0024..47bc` or a **valid** public key?

Comment: Yes, I've used snipped from MSDN page, and I've tried my plublickey also, but without solution

Answer (score 0):

Probably You should paste Public key generated by sn.exe tool.
Usually it stored somewhere like:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\sn.exe"
```

call it from command line:

```
sn.exe -p SomeName.snk SomeName.PublicKey
sn.exe -tp SomeName.PublicKey
```

and paste the output to the "InternalsVisibleTo" Public key param.

Important note from that msdn page that I missed: The Fakes framework uses the same key to sign all generated assemblies, so the public key if signing should ALWAYS be
`PublicKey=0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100e92de‌​cb949446f688ab9f6973436c535bf50acd1fd580495aae3f875aa4e4f663ca77908c63b7f0996977c‌​b98fcfdb35e05aa2c842002703cad835473caac5ef14107e3a7fae01120a96558785f48319f66daab‌​c862872b2c53f5ac11fa335c0165e202b4c011334c7bc8f4c4e570cf255190f4e3e2cbc9137ca57cb‌​687947bc`

Comment: I have followed this procedure, but the result does not change

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda weird I just replicated your problem and surely it wasn't generating the internals in Fake assembly at first. I followed below steps and it started working even for other namespaces too:

- Add a public class under the namespace `Utils`.
- Rebuild the Test project and the internal will start showing up.
- Remove that public class and rebuild again.

I removed everything from `Utils` namespace and added new internal class and it is working fine since then.
It's just a workaround to generate namespace that contains internals.

Comment: My Namespace is "ACQTool". I've a "Utils.cs" class with: internal class Utils, public enum LogSeveriry, public class DisabledEvents, public static class ExExtensions. I can see all casses except Utils